# Whiptail detects hyphen in name as a command

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to make a checklist using `whiptail` but when I enter one of the options it detects it as a command, even though it's in quotes. The point with this checklist is to bash a file and have the variables added to the end of the shell command during the bash i.e.

```
bash something.sh -cached_var_here
```

Here is the code and the error:

```bsh
BENCH=$(whiptail --title "Choose Benchmark Options" --checklist "Choose:" 20 
30 15 \
 "-info" "System Information" off \
 "-io" "System I/O Test" off \
 "-cdn" "CDN Test Download (200MB)" off \
 "-northamerica" "North-American Server Test Download (800MB)" off \
 "-europe" "European Server Test Download (900MB)" off \
 "-asia" "Asian Server Test Download (400MB)" off \
 "-b" "System Information, CDN Download Test & I/O Test" off \
 "-speed" "Network Speedtest Using speedtest-cli" off \
 "-share" "Share Your Results With Others!" off \
 "-help" "Help Menu. Do NOT Execute This With Other Options!" off \
 "-about" "Show About-Info. Do NOT Execute This With Other Options!" off \
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

echo "You chose the following options: $BENCH"
echo

echo "Do you want to run CUSTOM benchmark and information? (y/n)? "
old_stty_cfg=$(stty -g)
stty raw -echo
answer=$( while ! head -c 1 | grep -i '[ny]' ;do true ;done )
stty $old_stty_cfg
if echo "$answer" | grep -iq "^y" ;then
  echo Yes;

  curl -LsO raw.githubusercontent.com/sayem314/serverreviewbenchmark/master/bench.sh; chmod +x bench.sh
  echo
  ./bench.sh $BENCH
```

I get this error:

```
You chose the following options: -info: unknown option
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's consult `man whiptail`:

> `whiptail` interprets  arguments  starting  with  a  dash  "`-`"  as 
>   being
>          arguments.   To  avoid  this,  and  start  some text in, for example, a
>          menubox item, with a dash, `whiptail` honours the  `getopt`  convention  of
>          accepting  the  special  argument  "`--`"  which means that all following
>          arguments with dashes are to be treated  verbatim  and  not  parsed  as
>          options.

Therefore, the following approach should work like a charm:

```bsh
whiptail --title "Choose Benchmark Options" --checklist -- Choose: 20 30 15 -info "System Information" off
```